# Desktop App Converter/Submit to Windows Store

Tags: windows, converters, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I have an older application that I've converted using Microsoft's "Desktop App Converter" to create a UWP application.  The application appears to convert fine, and I can install and run it on my local machine.  Unfortunately, when I try to submit the application to the Windows App Store, I get the following errors:

Package acceptance validation error: We don't allow the capability you've specified: runFullTrust.

Package acceptance validation error: You don't have permissions to specify the following namespaces in the appx manifest file of the package DownloadManager.appx: http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities.

Are there any ideas what is causing this and what the fix is?

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise Preview Version 1511, Build 14352.1002

Comment: I have the same issue. I think its connected with coed like `[DllImport("user32.dll")]` (in my case). I dont know what to do...

Comment: Same here. A royal PITA if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

According to this article from the official blog, you cannot submit your Centennial apps to the Store just yet. You have to follow the process they mention in their article:

[Windows 10 Anniversary Update SDK Now Available! Windows Store Open for Submissions](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/08/02/windows-10-anniversary-update-sdk-14393/)

"Windows Store Open for Submissions; Including Process for Submitting Desktop Bridge Apps:

In addition, we will begin the process of accepting apps using the Desktop Bridge. While we build the pipeline into the Windows Store to publish these apps, our team will work directly with developers to get their converted apps and games into the Windows Store. Contact our team [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge) if you are interested in submitting an app using the Desktop Bridge to the Windows Store."

Answer (score 1):

You can find in this article [Preparing your desktop app for conversion to UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root#preparing-your-desktop-app-for-conversion-to-uwp) features that should be removed from codebase.
As I see there is one **Your app always runs with elevated security privileges**.
Check this one ar may be your app contains some another feature from list